# Stage will not render in libgdx, get null pointer error

Tags: java, android, libgdx, actor, stage

I am just trying to get Actor and Stage to work properly to set up a basic flow and then move on from there. I get a null pointer to stage every time, help please. The Paddle and Ball class are identical right now, Assets is a static class for loading textures.

```
public class MyGame implements ApplicationListener {
public final static int WIDTH = 480;
public final static int HEIGHT = 800;
private Stage stage;
private Paddle paddle;
private Ball ball;




@Override
public void create () {
    Assets.load();
    Stage stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    paddle = new Paddle();
    ball = new Ball();
    stage.addActor(paddle);
    stage.addActor(ball);


}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.draw();

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height){
    stage.getViewport().update(width,height,true);

}

@Override
public void dispose(){
    Assets.dispose();
    stage.dispose();


}

public int getWidth(){return WIDTH;}
public int getHeight(){return HEIGHT;}
```

}

```
public class Paddle extends Actor {


Rectangle bounds;


public Paddle(){

    setPosition(150,10);


}

@Override
public void act(float delta){

}


public void draw(Batch batch , float parentAlpha){

    batch.draw(Assets.paddle,150,10 );
}

private void updateBounds() {bounds.set(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
}
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return bounds;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you create a `Stage` in the create method, but you never asign it to your private member `stage`.
So instead of writing `Stage stage = new Stage()` in the `create` just write `stage = new Stage()`.
Also remember to add the `Exception` and it's `Stack Trace` to your SO-Question and mark the line in which the `Exception` seems to occure. It will make it much easier for everybody who wants to help.

Comment: @user1810577 did the answer solve your problem? If so, please accept this or the other answer (same solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second Stage declaration if the same varible "stage"

```
@Override
public void create () {
    Assets.load();
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport()); 
    paddle = new Paddle();
    ball = new Ball();
    stage.addActor(paddle);
    stage.addActor(ball);


}
```